# Jenkins build is not picking up and running Unit Test Cases written in SpockFramewok

Tags: java, unit-testing, jenkins, spock

I have written almost 50 test cases using Spock framework for my java application. When I try to build my application, my spock unit tests are not running. Also build was not showing up any errors related to these test cases.

Here are the test results that are published from Jenkins log :

**Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.201 sec**

Results :

**Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0**

I have the following plug in configuration in my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
            </includes>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

**Example Test file name** : BusinessApplicationTest.groovy

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue ?

** Update **

Issue got resolved by adding the following gmavenplus plugin.

```html
     
**Issue got resolved by adding the following gmavenplus plugin.**

> <plugin> <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
> <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId> <version>1.5</version>
> <executions> <execution> <goals> <goal>compile</goal>
> <goal>testCompile</goal> </goals> </execution> </executions> </plugin>
```

Comment: Where are those files? Are they getting compiled into `test-classes`?

Comment: Which is the `mvn` command run by Jenkins? Does it work on your local machine?

Comment: Executing Maven:  -B -f /workspace/*/pom.xml clean test -U

Comment: Chrylis, the groovy files were compiled into test-classes folder (package folder) with the extension of .class

Comment: You instructed sure-fire to look for files like BusinessApplicationTest.java but name them BusinessApplicationTest.groovy?  Try changing your pattern to **/*Test.groovy

Comment: @mikejramsey56 they compile to Java when they're picked up to run. That part isn't the issue.

Comment: Ah, but the filter is looking for files **to** compile and **then** run. :-)

Comment: I could see class files under  \target\test-classes\<package-name> folder with .class extension. The output files are being generated from .groovy files. But somehow not picking them up to execute the test cases.

Comment: Which folder path do you have your tests under? Does it match that specified by <testSourceDirectory> in your pom.xml under <build> ?